# c# form increasing memory + runs slower and slower over time

Tags: c#, forms

I have a more or less realtime app form developed to run MODBUS RTU diagnostics.
The realtime parts are within whileloops, which are in a thread, which starts every new message.
The old thread closes with a boolean set to false, then in the mainthread a .join(50) and then a check if the thread has closes and if not, a hard abort.
Thereafter the thread becomes null (= null).
All timers (system forms timers) I use stays running (just start/stop). 
The first problem I encountered was that one timer (running as a watchdogtimer) didn't fire interrups after 10seconds of no communication.
After doing some research, I found something about garbage collector etc.
So I did a second timer and a =new timer().
But still no events firering.
Now I also see the used memory increasing over time, while the communication becomes slower and slower.
After a fresh restart my app uses 32MB of memory and fires 10-15 messages/sec.
After 10 hours, the app uses 350MB of memory and fires only 0,9-1,2 messages/sec.
I checked all used variables, made those all null, uses disposes() etc.etc.
It's such a simple form, just 2 rich textboxes (which I already limit on max size, by cutting the .Text to a max of 250 chars in this way: `

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Insert(0, "Hello world!"); 
Array.Resize(...);
```

My questions are:
- How can I check what element is responsible for this memory increasing over time?
- What elements could be the reason, or what elements are known causes?

**EDIT: Problem has been solved**
The problem has to be the GC collector (Garbage Controller) which doesn't follow the high throughput of data.
For every message a new thread started in the first application setup (which was just some bulk of code for test purpose of a connected embedded device).
 
Despite all the =null and .disposes() somehow the GC gets stuck on the lots of new and freed variables and threads.
Now I have rewritten the whole part with just some static threads running whileloops, which doesn't close, but only when they freeze, started reading/writing using booleans like b_StartWrite and b_StartReceive.
Each whileloop has a variable like `ReceiveThreadStatus`, which I set to 1 before the receive starts, where the receive thread sets this var to 2, which in turn the mainthread checks.
If the var didn't change, the receive thread has freezed and the mainthread cleans and restarts this receive thread.
The main timer (1 ms timer event) starts & checks in turn the mainthread.
Maybe a nice update should be the sleep and suspend for the threads, so the processor doesn't have to run @30% the whole time... but thats for a later moment.
After 14 hours the app just consumes 25,8MB and still fires 15 messages/second, so the embedded devices are under a stable test now:)
.
Also writing `GC.Collect()` after each thread stop doesn't solve this slow-down issue.
Another possibility is to use `Server Mode` GC, as explained here: [Configuring Garbage Collection on the Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165011(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Use a memory profiler

Comment: Try to post your code in order to get better solution

Comment: this sounds like events that dont get cleaned up. Check if there are any loops or functions that add an eventhandler to an event, and then check how often they get called. To help you more we need code

Comment: Please post your code. It sounds like you're not disposing of `IDisposable` objects and/or not detaching events, but we can't tell without the code.

Comment: Also: Add a few line breaks to you question. As it is it is very hard to read.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the question, as it was nicely aligned when writing;) I figured out the memory leak cames from moving the mouse pointer over the form. But I have no mouse hoover nor mouse move event... so something is triggering something in background, which eat some memory, but aren't freed there after...

Comment: Please avoid editing your question to add the solution. Instead, post the solution as an answer you your own question and accept it after 48 hours. 
[For more information, read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)